# JQuery animate() not working as intended in conjunction with removeClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to implement my own carousel as a way to teach myself javascript and have come across a problem where the animation prior to my removeClass call doesn't occur but the animation for bringing in the next element works as intended.

I realize this sounds quite vague so I've reproduced my problem with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f57N3/

I've also included the relevant code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="button-container">
    <button id="b2">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box active-box" id="box1">
        thingy
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box2">
        other thingy
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box3">
        another thingy
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;

    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;

    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

.active-box{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

.container{
    width: 850px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #003399;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// Functionality for 'Next' button
$("#b2").click(function(){

    var thisBox = $(".active-box");
    var nextBox = thisBox.next();
    if(nextBox.length == 0){
        nextBox = $(".box").first();
    }

    // Set pre-animation conditions
    thisBox.css("margin-left", "0px");
    thisBox.css("opacity", "1");

    // Animate this box and remove active class
    thisBox.animate({marginLeft: "-=300px", opacity: "0"}, 800).removeClass("active-box");

    //Set pre-animation conditions
    nextBox.css("margin-left", "300px");
    nextBox.css("opacity", "0");

    // Animate this box and add active class
    nextBox.animate({marginLeft: "-=300px", opacity: "1"}, 800).addClass("active-box");
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animate has a `complete` function you can pass to it http://api.jquery.com/animate/

What was happening was that the `removeClass` was firing straight away.  only `removing` in the `complete` seems to solve that.  Also moving the following into that makes it run smoother.

```
// Functionality for 'Next' button
$("#b2").click(function () {
    var thisBox = $(".active-box");
    var nextBox = thisBox.next();
    if (nextBox.length == 0) {
        nextBox = $(".box").first();
    }
    // Set pre-animation conditions
    thisBox.css("margin-left", "0px");
    thisBox.css("opacity", "1");
    // Animate this box and remove active class
    thisBox.animate({
        marginLeft: "-=300px",
        opacity: "0"
    }, 800, 'swing', function () {
        thisBox.removeClass("active-box");
        //Set pre-animation conditions
        nextBox.css("margin-left", "300px");
        nextBox.css("opacity", "0");
        // Animate this box and add active class
        nextBox.animate({
            marginLeft: "-=300px",
            opacity: "1"
        }, 800).addClass("active-box");
    })

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/f57N3/1/

Comment: The text says to not do this here, but thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for the last week already!

Comment: The initial value of the textbox says to use comments for suggestions or information and not thank yous

Comment: @Ambit! Ah yes! Sorry I thought you were talking about the methodology of the answer! You can always delete a little while after.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this maybe :

**Javascript :**

```
$("#b2").click(function(){

var thisBox = $(".active-box");
var nextBox = thisBox.next();
if(nextBox.length == 0){
    nextBox = $(".box").first();
}

// Set pre-animation conditions
thisBox.css("margin-left", "0px");
thisBox.css("opacity", "1");

// Animate this box and remove active class
thisBox.animate({marginLeft: "-=300px", opacity: "0"}, 800);
thisBox.removeClass("active-box");

//Set pre-animation conditions
nextBox.css("margin-left", "300px");
nextBox.css("opacity", "0");

// Animate this box and add active class
nextBox.animate({marginLeft: "-=300px", opacity: "1"}, 800);
nextBox.addClass("active-box");
});
```